# PowerShell How substitute multiple files in a path

Tags: file, powershell, while-loop

I am a newbie to powershell and need some assistance.
I have some example of script

```
1..10| % { #count of iteration
   While (@(Get-Job | Where { $_.State -eq "Running" }).Count -ge $MaxThreads)
   { 
     Write-Host "Waiting for open thread...($MaxThreads Maximum)"
     Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 #rump-up period
    }
   $Scriptblock = {
   param($name)
   & "ConsoleUI.exe" mode/s  savetodisk/true filepath/C:\6383.incoming
   Write-Host "Result of request № $name" $LASTEXITCODE 
   "Result of request № $name $LASTEXITCODE" | Out-File C:\results.txt -Append
   }
   Start-Job -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock -ArgumentList $_  
}
```

I have a few files like "111.incoming", "222.incoming", "333.incoming" in dir "C:\test", and I need to substitute their in filepath/C:...   in turn in loop.
Is any way to do that? 
Thanks.

Comment: Working code 

      $filelist = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -File *.incoming
      foreach ($item in $filelist){
      $Scriptblock = {
   param($name)
      & "ConsoleUI.exe" mode/s savetodisk/true filepath/C:\$name
      Write-host "Result of request № $name" $LASTEXITCODE  
      }
      Start-Job -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock -ArgumentList $item
      }

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention whether or not you needed to pass all the files to ConsoleUI.exe at once, or if you needed to pass them in one-by-one.  I'm going to guess the latter, e.g., pass them to ConsoleUI.exe one-by-one.

I'm also using aliases like **DIR** for `Get-ChildItem` and **SELECT** for `Select-Object`, to match your current usage.

```
$Scriptblock = {
param($name)
DIR 'C:\test\*.incoming' | Select -Expand FullName | % {
    & "ConsoleUI.exe" mode/s  savetodisk/true filepath/$_
    Write-Host "Result of request № $name, file $_ $LASTEXITCODE" 
    "Result of request № $name, file $_ $LASTEXITCODE" | Out-File C:\results.txt -Append
    }
}
```